# Converting RTF file with images to TIFF

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I got my .rtf file I generated using MSWord, and I added some images to it, it has 28000 lines, and now I'm trying to convert that rtf file to tiff image. Here's the code I have:

```
 static void ConvertRtfToTiff(string rtfFilePath, string outputDirectory)
 {
     // Create output directory if it doesn't exist
     if (!Directory.Exists(outputDirectory))
     {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
     }

     // Load RTF content using FileStream and StreamReader
     string rtfContent;
     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(rtfFilePath, FileMode.Open))
     {
         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
         {
             rtfContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
     }

     // Create a RichTextBox control to load the RTF content
     using (RichTextBox richTextBox = new RichTextBox())
     {
         // Set the size of the RichTextBox
         int width = (int)(8.27 * 100); // A4 width in pixels (assuming 100 DPI)
         int height = (int)(11.69 * 100); // A4 height in pixels (assuming 100 DPI)
         richTextBox.Size = new Size(width, height);
         richTextBox.Multiline = true;
         richTextBox.ReadOnly = true;

         // Assign RTF content to the RichTextBox
         richTextBox.Rtf = rtfContent;

         // Iterate through the RTF content and extract images
         int imageCount = 0;
         foreach (var image in GetImagesFromRtf(richTextBox))
         {
             string imagePath = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, $"image_{imageCount}.tiff");

             // Delete the output file if it already exists
             if (File.Exists(imagePath))
             {
                 File.Delete(imagePath);
             }

             // Save the image as TIFF format
             image.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Tiff);

             Console.WriteLine($"Image saved: {imagePath}");
             imageCount++;
         }
     }
 }
```

I found out that this line

```
// Assign RTF content to the RichTextBox
richTextBox.Rtf = rtfContent;
```

doesn't copy rtfContent to richTextBox full. It copies like 20 lines.

I am no RTF expert, so I don't understand why it's not being fully copied, nor how I can make it so, and thus the questions:

Why is it not copying the contents fully?
How could I fix this?

Comment: Try [RichTextBox.LoadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) Method.

Comment: From which library `GetImagesFromRtf` method?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe after the assignment `richTextBox.Rtf = rtfContent;`, you need to let the component draw. The good old `Application.DoEvents()` is rushing to the rescue. Eh?

Comment: Why would you need a RichTextBox for this? Then `.ReadOnly`, trying to size it as an A4? What for? Did you omit some relevant information here?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov tried, I get the same result :(

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov it's my function, I was debugging that first but in the end I noticed that this function is not getting the "whole picture" (notice the pun)

Comment: @Jimi I tried not to omit relevant info. I'm working in windows forms project, and this code is generated by ChatGPT, though I have an understanding of what I asked for and how it's all working, and it does work well, and the thing I don't understand is just why `richTextBox.Rtf` neglects 99% of the `rtfContent`. It's the only thing I ask here because my goal was to explain the exact problem I'm having, not omit information, so sorry if it seems that way. `Readonly` and `Multiline` are properties I thought would make a change, but they don't.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I doubt that letting the component draw after `richTextBox.Rtf = rtfContent;` will change something, because I've put a breakpoint at the line after it, and I can clearly see that `rtfContent` has all my file's contents, and the `richTextBox.Rtf` has like 20 lines of that.

Comment: You don't need a RichTextBox at all. Besides, the RTF generated by Word is not entirely compatible with the RTF model that the RTB can handle. You need to extract images from the RTF, right? The RTB does nothing for your; and it's not clear what the `GetImagesFromRtf()` method is actually accomplishing, or why you're passing the instance of a Control to it, instead of the original RTF

Comment: @Jimi hm... well then all this code is going to trash I suppose. I want to convert RTF file to a TIFF file. The `GetImagesFromRtf` function does exactly what it says. reads the content and checks for image task like `\pict` and tries to convert them to an `Image` class. Is it possible to convert Microsoft's RTF format to an image without using payed third party APIs?

Comment: Are you saying that the `GetImagesFromRtf()` method does what it's supposed to do? How does it do it? How is a Control involved? The RTB doesn't expose any method or property that allows to directly handle embedded images, and it doesn't appear you're showing this Control in a Form, it's just used as container (a most probably incompatible one) for unknown reasons. You just need to Regex the original RTF (or parse it in any other way) -- If you want a free parser, [this is one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter)